# This website in Arduino lists language references like functions and structures. What makes structures there different from functions?

Tags: functions

https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/

**Language Reference**

Arduino programming language can be divided in three main parts: functions, values (variables and constants), and structure.

**functions**

For controlling the Arduino board and performing computations.

**variables**

Arduino data types and constants.

**structure**

The elements of Arduino (C++) code.

I find it really confusing that they had to separate the structures but also call them functions in their descriptions. I kind of want to get a visualization or organization of the different language references present in Arduino, but this just confuses me. Are structures in the website also functions, and mainly syntax can be classified into functions and variables? Can someone present a organization of language references that doesn't involve terminologies being mixed up?

Comment: please provide an example of what confuses you

Comment: perhaps it may clear your thoughts if you review C++ programming

Comment: They're playing loose with terms.  If you want a clearer understanding of C++ the C++ standard itself is a better reference.

Answer (score 2):

What the website names "Structures" are code building-blocks for the programs you write. The main part there are conditional (if-else) and loop instructions (for, while) as well as mathematical operators. You use these constructs *within* your functions to control program flow or compute results. Functions, on the other hand, are sub-programs you can call to have certain tasks done. They might be pre-defined (such as the ones described on the language reference page) or written by yourself.

Now there are two exceptions to this rule, and maybe that's what's a bit confusing in the documentation: The functions `setup()` and `loop()`. These are functions, but make up the structure of your program. They are the main building blocks of an Arduino sketch, and that's probably why they're mentioned under "Structures".

Comment: Yes, this is the kind of explanation I am looking for. Someone who has a clear visual of their own with how the hierarchy of how the types of code are. It makes it really clear that under programs, we can put functions and under that we can put structures. Yes, the set up and loop is confusing but I would prefer categorizing it as functions because you can put structures inside.
I'd like to ask, what references do you use for Arduino? You seem to have a good personal grasp on terminologies.

Comment: Actually, I use exactly that page for things that are arduino-specific, and any other resources I find for any C++ issues I come across. The Arduino compiler is a full-featured C++ compiler, with almost all the features the normal GCC also has. The library functions are also all there, so if you need help for things like `malloc` or `free` just use your preferred search engine. (One exception here: STL support is not available out-of-the-box).